# Unexpected syntax error on "for" looping with json array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to looping a json array on php. But unexpectedly it showing

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ';' in /home/windsys/public_html/siddiqa/function/ordermedicine.php on line 13

I'm not sure why it's showing syntax error on line 13. I've checked carefully. Please tell me where is the wrong.

```
<?php
require_once('../configuration.php');
$con=new mysqli($hostname,$dbusername,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    die('The connection to the database could not be established.');
}
$obj = $_POST['data'];
//print_r($obj);
//echo $_POST['medicine_name'];
echo $obj[0]['medicine_name'];
$objcount=count($obj);
echo count($obj);
for(i=0;i<count($obj);i++){
echo $obj[i]['medicine_name'];

}

?>
```

Comment: Change `i` to `$i`. PHP thinks that `i` is a constant, but because it has not been defined it will just assume that it is a string. Because it is not possible to assign a value to a string you are getting a parse error.

Comment: are you sure you have written `for(i=0;i<count($obj);i++)` and not `for($i=0;$i<count($obj);$i++)`? Or is it a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
for(i=0;i<count($obj);i++){
  echo $obj[i]['medicine_name'];
}
```

to

```
for($i=0;$i<count($obj);$i++){
  echo $obj[$i]['medicine_name'];
}
```

ypu are working with php variable so define every vars with `$`

Answer (score 0):

Hello you forgot **$**

it should be

```
for($i=0;$i<count($obj);$i++){
    echo $obj[$i]['medicine_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `$obj[i]['medicine_name'];` change `i` to `$i`. as well as with the `i` used on the `for` loop.